# iphone -- running XCode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK on iPod Touch 2nd Generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I've been having trouble getting my app to run in this configuration.  Has anyone figured out how to do this?  Currently, my app doesn't even show up when I try to run on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Deployment target of your Project to lower firmware version (f.e. 4.3), because  iOS 5 is still beta, we are not allowed to run the aps on it.

Comment: Wait, I'm not allowed to test my Apps against iOS 5 to test if they are compatible with it, although I'm a developer with access to the beta? Sucks man.

Comment: no, false. You can obviously test you apps against iOS5 (of course! and hopefully! It would be useless to have access to the beta otherwise!), if you keep your tests either on the simulator or on your own devices. What you're not allowed to do obviously is to publish applications on the AppStore using this SDK yet or share it with others.

Answer (score 4):

iOS5 is **not supported** by iPod Touch 2nd Gen.

No wonder why you're having trouble ;)